# Vim .vimrc custom location

Tags: vim

I have used the bare bones of Vim under Ubuntu and now I would like to update my .vimrc file.  Although Vim is indeed installed on my PC I don't seem to have a .vimrc file.  I would like to add my .vimrc file but it really should go under my ~/.vim/ folder (I like to keep all my configurations in their respected folders).

How does one create a new vimrc file under this location in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: I'd love to do this, actually. Then I can just initialize a git repo in that directory and cover everything!

Comment: @BenjaminRH if you set the backupdir and undodir under your `.vim`, like what I did, think twice before you pushed "everything" to github. personally, I think backup/versioning `.vimrc` file would be enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options. (Take a look at `:h vimrc` which describes the default location and the -u option)

Create an alias to `vim -u ~/.vim/vimrc` this will cause vim to use that vimrc instead of `~/.vimrc`

Or

Upgrade to vim 7.4. One of its default vimrc locations is `~/.vim/vimrc`

---

You can also simulate the vimrc being in a different place.

Create a ~/.vimrc file that contains

```
runtime vimrc
```

It's job is to load the first file named vimrc in your runtime path. Which should be `~/.vim/vimrc`

Or

You could just symlink ~/.vim/vimrc to ~/.vimrc

```
ln -s $HOME/.vim/vimrc $HOME/.vimrc
```

(I've heard some people have had problems with this but I haven't so far)

Comment: +1. how about add the `:h initialization` The info (-u and default locations) are explained there.

Comment: @kent I would except I'm on my phone. I'll do that when I get back to my computer.

Comment: I wish I could +1 again. for so much typing work with a phone! btw, don't tell me you used vim on phone too....

Comment: @FDinoff I use vim from my phone from time to time.  ConnectBot SSH has a convenient thing to hit ESC, and with that it's smooth sailing.

Comment: i have vim installed on my iphone.  but do use it in a shell all the time via prompt.

Comment: Great info about the use of `.vim/vimrc` by default. It will really simplify the management of preferences on multiple machines.

Comment: FWIW, I think creating a `~/.vimrc` with `runtime vimrc` in it is a better way to go (the second solution).

Comment: +1 for symlinks for .vimrc. I like to keep all [my dotfiles](https://github.com/nathanlong/dotfiles) and vim config in the same place under version control. I keep a separate sheet source from my vimrc for local overrides. Fantastic for keeping an environment consistent across multiple computers.